# trying to trigger even when navigating from Usercontrol windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, user-controls

Yesterday I was refactoring some code in my windows phone project to try and use mvvm. I added binding to the toggleswitched on the page etc. the previous code also had evenhandlers for each toggleswitches checked and unchecked events. anyway I managed to clean it up. But my problem occured when I was trying to get code in my viewmodel to execute when i navigated away from this page. Initially I tried this

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    viewmodel.SaveSettings();    

}
```

after a bit of time debugging. I found this method wasnt being called. This was due to the fact that I was calling it in the code behind of a UserControl. Ive also tried to call the OnLostfocus() method when navigating away from the User control. but this doesnt work either. for the most part the project swaps in and out usercontrol elements in the main xaml.cs. mainly iam not really sure how to go about getting this method to be called when the usercontrol exits without destroying the mvvm structure i have i place  now. any  help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:
oKay i figured this out. In my main.xaml is had a user contorls beign swapped in and out depending on menu item press by the user. the usercontorl in the main xaml looked like this

```
 <UserControl x:Name="ActiveUserControl" Height="Auto" Width="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0"/>
```

and it was swapped in and out using this command in the xaml.cs

```
ActiveUserControl.Content = _userControls["controlname"];
```

_usercontrols was just a dictionary of usercontrols. so in the onnavigatedfrom method in the main.xaml i changed the content of the ActiveuserControl  to some other usercontrol. so if the home key was pressed on this usercontrol it would firethe unloaded event which fired then in the usercontol code behind this way it saved my settings.

Comment: Under mvvm some events are not accesible. I my self with this problem had to call a function from the view where the navigation occurs.

Comment: yes, Iam working on a project where another developer has all the app created on one xaml page and usercontrols are swaped in and out. which doesnt really allow me to use onnavigatedfrom().

Comment: But couldn't you use onbackkeypressed() ? Of course you would need to access the the event in the view, and therefore still have to call mainviewmodel.

Comment: onbackeypressed() eh? havent tried that yet. ill check it out.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work. unnfortunately

Comment: WHat I used was the UnLoaded event in the code behind. so when another usercontrol is added to the backstack the unloaded event is fired so i can the call the webservices

Comment: obviously this doesnt account for the app being closed

Comment: Okay, that would be solved with backkeypressed, but if that does not work, I am out of Ideas :)

Comment: whats backkeypressed? doesnt seem to be an event called this in the usercontrol

Comment: Anyway seems Like ill have to use a dependencyproperty in this instance dont know much about it so ive got reading to do. when I get a solution ill post it

Comment: Sorry no you cannot use Backkeypressed in the usercontrol, it as protected event that can be overrided in the view where you call your usercontrollers.